# How to use parent project's class from a child project

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

There is a project contains a child project in xcode. The child project needs to visit the source code of its parent project. How to do that? Now I am using forwarding class (@class) in the .m files of child project, but xcode complains that the methods called to the class may not be found. How to suppress the warning or is there any other better solution? Thanks for any help.

Edit:
The child project create a .a library for the parent project. I just want to use parent project's class in the library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

xcode complains that the methods called to the class may not be found because your parent project not getting any reference of your child Project.

Drag your child project into Parent Project and follow below steps:

You need to set Header search path of your child project into parent project.

Follow below steps:

Xcode->Targets->Build setting->Header Search Path.

Hope You understand !!

Good Luck !!!

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps I'm not understanding your question, but I think all you should have to do is click on the relevant file in the file window of XCode and then, on the right sidebar, click the correct checkbox under Target Membership. Then the files should compile along with both targets; as it stands your second target doesn't know where to find the files you wrote in the first. That should work (if I understand your question correctly, anyway).

Comment: The project has only one target.